# django multiple installation problem

Tags: django

Have django serving different settings file & database based on subdomains. The virtual host entries are manually added to apache.

There are currently two subdomains with different databases. First one is working okay, the second one is not displaying any css/images.

Apache configuration is as, there are two of them

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.domain.com
ServerAlias test.domain.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/site/

    <Location "/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings.test
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/var/www/site/'] + sys.path"
    </location>
    <location "/public/media">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
    <location "/public/admin_media">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
    <location "/static">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
 </VirtualHost>
```

The content of subdomain having issues with displaying css/images , are in /public/media folder. If accessed directly via http://test.domain.com/public/media/images/image.jpg , the images are there.

Comment: This is a terrible question. You don't show any of your configuration to help us debug the problem. In any case, serving assets is an Apache configuration issue, which belongs on serverfault.com.

Comment: Apache configuration is added

Comment: please provide at least path for missing css/images and configuration of it for apache.

it is quite difficult to imagine/guess what author wanted to ask for..

Comment: path not showing up is public/media folder

Comment: are you using the MEDIA_URL in settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was session/cookie problem. Added SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to settings.py with subdomain , seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

1) Note that you are not loading the default "settings.py", but "settings/test.py".

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings.test
```

So maybe it should be:

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings
```

or

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings.production
```

2) Make sure you have this, in whatever your settings file is:

```
DEBUG = False
MEDIA_URL = "/public/media"
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = "/public/admin_media"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you uses two different virtualhosts for the two different subdomains.

Subdomain test1.domain.com
    
    ServerName test1.domain.com

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/site/

    <Location "/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings.test
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/var/www/site/'] + sys.path"
    </location>
    <location "/public/media">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
    <location "/public/admin_media">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
    <location "/static">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Subdomain test2.domain.com
    
    ServerName test2.domain.com

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/site/

    <Location "/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE site.settings.test
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/var/www/site/'] + sys.path"
    </location>
    <location "/public/media">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
    <location "/public/admin_media">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
    <location "/static">
        SetHandler None
    </location>
 </VirtualHost>
```